# Play Audio File If Time Matches

Tags: c#

Why can't I get this audio file played when the time in `textboxordertostart.Text` in string format equals the system time? `Textboxordertostart` gets time after subtracting minutes from `DateTimePicker` time.

My code is as follow.

```
SoundPlayer myplayer = new SoundPlayer();

myplayer.SoundLocation= (@"c:\users\woolsvalley\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication17\WindowsFormsApplication17\Alarm.wav");


if (DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt") == textBox_ordertostart.Text)
{ 
    myplayer.Play(); 
}
```

This code throws a null exception

```
string formatString = "yyyHHmmss";
        string sample = textBox_ordertostart.Text;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(sample, formatString, null);
        if (DateTime.Now == dt)
        { myplayer.Play(); }
```

this is not working as well

```
if (DateTime.Now == DateTime.Parse(textBox_ordertostart.Text))
        { myplayer.Play(); }
```

Comment: What's the value for `textBox_ordertostart.Text`?  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see?

Comment: I would set a breakpoint on the conditional line, and manually examine what `DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt")` returns.  You should be able to compare it to the value you typed in the textbox and easily see why they don't match.

Comment: does your `textBox_ordertostart.Text` returns a value similar to this `00:00 PM` ?

Comment: As I mention in my answer, this is a very "rigid" way of doing the comparison. You need to parse the content of the textbox as a DateTime first and then it becomes much easier to compare them.

Comment: Thanks guys! There is a label in my form which takes system time as            DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt")   just to display the system time. Because both the label and textbox have string format, i compared them as well but still file is not playing. I'll try parse text to datetime. Let u know guys...

Answer (score 2):

The way you're doing the comparison is a very "brittle" way of doing the comparison because it's dependent on the user typing the time in the exact format you're expecting it in. For example, when I tested this, I got the following results:

```
string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt");

// False
Console.WriteLine(datetime == "2:06 PM");

        // False
        Console.WriteLine(datetime == "2:06 P.M.");
        // False
        Console.WriteLine(datetime == "2:06");

        // False
        Console.WriteLine(datetime == "02:06 P.M.");

        // True
        Console.WriteLine(datetime == "02:06 PM");
```

If you parse it to a DateTime object and then do ToString, it'll be less brittle though. See this extension method, for example:

```
public static bool DayMinuteEqual(this string otherDate)
    {
        // We have to strip out the "." character if present (e.g. 2:05 P.M.)
        DateTime otherDateObj = DateTime.Parse(otherDate.Replace(".", ""));

        return DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt") == otherDateObj.ToString("hh:mm tt");
    }
```

Now I get the results I expect:

```
// True
        Console.WriteLine("2:20 PM".DayMinuteEqual());

        // True
        Console.WriteLine("2:20 P.M.".DayMinuteEqual());

        // False, but we'd expect it due to the omission of the "P.M."
        Console.WriteLine("2:20".DayMinuteEqual());

        // True
        Console.WriteLine("02:20 P.M.".DayMinuteEqual());

        // True
        Console.WriteLine("02:20 PM".DayMinuteEqual());
```

Clearly, then, this much less dependent on the user entering the date in a "perfect" format (but still requires them to have *some* sense of the correct format).

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys. This code works i just needed to raise it in the updating event.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   label_time1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt");
        mplayer = new SoundPlayer();
        mplayer.SoundLocation = (@"c:\users\woolsvalley\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication17\WindowsFormsApplication17\Alarm.wav");
        if((DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm tt") == ((textBox_ordertostart.Text))))
        { mplayer.Play(); }
```